# Chack number from contacts is mobile or fixed line(landline) number

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, contacts, phone-number

I wanted to have a check whether the phone number getting from the contacts is a Mobile number or a fixed line(landline) number. I have tried using the regrex but all is in vain..any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Is this library considered ineligible in your case? https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS It does distinguish mobile vs fixed line

Answer (score 1):

For filtering contact by mobile number and landline you need have list of std code in database and then you can check if immediate digits after country code match std code then it's landline. You can search for such api as well.

Try : http://www.searchbug.com/api/

Comment: Thanks, I can not use the 3rd party things in the app due to client's requirements :(   and for your suggestion to keep all the std codes in a database seems to be a least choice, so if possible suggest me some alternate.

Comment: then I am sorry don't know easy way then having all in database.